# configuration file for a standalone ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ruby script that runs on a linux server. Its not using rails or anything. Its basically a commandline ruby script that can be passed arguments like this: `./ruby_script.rb arg1 arg2`

How can I abstract away the arguments into a configuration file such as a yaml file or something? Can you provide an example of how this can be done?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you can run an independent script that writes to a YAML configuration file:

```
require "yaml"
File.write("path_to_yaml_file", [arg1, arg2].to_yaml)
```

Then, read it within your app:

```
require "yaml"
arg1, arg2 = YAML.load_file("path_to_yaml")
# use arg1, arg2
...
```

Comment: whats the point of writing a yaml and then reading from that same yaml??

Comment: Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to get data from that file. Are you expecting to write something to file A, and then reading that data by accessing a different file B? That does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the system I wrote as part of [neomind-dashboard-public](https://github.com/NeomindLabs/neomind-dashboard-public), a standalone Ruby script [under the open-source MIT License](https://github.com/NeomindLabs/neomind-dashboard-public/blob/master/LICENSE.txt).

Your project’s [`config` folder](https://github.com/NeomindLabs/neomind-dashboard-public/tree/master/config) should contain a `config.yml` file with your configuration data, like [this](https://github.com/NeomindLabs/neomind-dashboard-public/blob/master/config/config.example.yml):

```
updater script:
  code URL: https://github.com/NeomindLabs/neomind-dashboard-public

Leftronic dashboard:
  dashboard access key: 'bGVmdHJvbmljaXNhd2Vz' # find on https://www.leftronic.com/api/
  stream names:

    statuses for CI project names:
      "Project Alpha": project_alpha_ci_status
      "Project Beta": project_beta_ci_status
      "Project Gamma": project_gamma_ci_status
# etc.
```

Copy the file [`lib/config_loader.rb`](https://github.com/NeomindLabs/neomind-dashboard-public/blob/master/lib/config_loader.rb) to your project. It’s a very small file that uses [the built-in `yaml` library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) to load the YAML config file.

```
# encoding: utf-8

require 'yaml'

class ConfigLoader
  def initialize
    load_config_data
  end

  def [](name)
    config_for(name)
  end

  def config_for(name)
    @config_data[name]
  end

  private

  def load_config_data
    config_file_path = 'config/config.yml'
    begin
      config_file_contents = File.read(config_file_path)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT
      $stderr.puts "missing config file"
      raise
    end
    @config_data = YAML.load(config_file_contents)
  end
end
```

Finally, in each file that uses the config file, follow this pattern (this example comes from the file [`lib/dashboard_updater.rb`](https://github.com/NeomindLabs/neomind-dashboard-public/blob/master/lib/dashboard_updater.rb)):

#### require the library

```
require_relative 'config_loader'
```

#### load `CONFIG` constant with your first-level key in the config file

```
class DashboardUpdater
  CONFIG = ConfigLoader.new.config_for("Leftronic dashboard")
```

#### use `CONFIG` to read configuration data

```
  def initialize_updater
    access_key = CONFIG["dashboard access key"]
    @updater = Leftronic.new(access_key)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an `undefined local variable or method` error when reading from the YAML file using the method in the accepted answer. I did it in a slightly different way:

Write to it as above:

```
require "yaml"
File.write("path/to/yaml", ["test_arg_1", "test_arg_2"].to_yaml)
```

Read from using a slight variation:

```
require "yaml"
arg1, arg2 = YAML.load(File.read("path/to/yaml"))

puts arg1
#=> test_arg_1
puts arg2
#=> test_arg_2
```